# Good Counter Design or Possible Metastability Issues?

Tags: counter, verilog

Quick summary of my goal:
Design a counter triggered by a variable length auto-reload timer.

A little more verbose: There will be a register with a value that changes (predictably changes, and is latched before the EN signal for the AutoReloadTimer module) that sets the rate at which the counter increments.

Here's the auto-reload timer:

```
module AutoReloadTimer( clk, rst, EN, D, done );
    input  clk;
    input  rst;
    input  EN;
    input  [WIDTH-1:0] D;
    output done;

    parameter WIDTH = 8;

    // OneShot EN -> load
    wire load;
    OneShotD OneShot_D(
        .clk( clk ),
        .rst( rst ),
        .in( EN ),
        .RE( load )
    );

    reg [WIDTH-1:0] counter, load_value;

    always @( posedge clk ) begin
        if ( rst ) begin
            counter     <= {WIDTH{1'b1}};
            load_value  <= {WIDTH{1'b1}};
        end else if ( load ) begin
            counter     <= D;
            load_value  <= D;
        end else if (counter == 0 ) begin
            counter     <= load_value;
            load_value  <= load_value;
        end else begin
            counter     <= counter - 1'b1;
            load_value  <= load_value;
        end
    end

    assign done = ( counter == 0 );

endmodule
```

And here is the counter triggered by the done signal from the AutoReloadTimer module:

```
module Counter( clk, rst, EN, CLR, Q );
    input  clk;
    input  rst;
    input  EN;
    input  CLR;
    output [WIDTH-1:0] Q;

    parameter WIDTH = 8;

    reg [WIDTH-1:0] ctr;

    always @( posedge clk ) begin
        if ( rst ) begin
            ctr <= {WIDTH{1'b0}};
        end else if ( CLR ) begin
            ctr <= {WIDTH{1'b0}};
        end else if ( EN ) begin
            ctr <= ctr + 1'b1;
        end else begin
            ctr <= ctr;
        end
    end

    assign Q = ctr;
endmodule
```

And here is a portion of the waveform from a testbench:
[image: Counter Waveform]

What I'm curious about here is my counter's stability - is it an issue that the done signal goes low at the rising edge of the clock? I'm still fairly new to Verilog and digital design. I'm familiar with the term and somewhat the idea of metastability but I'm not fully comfortable with my understanding of it.

Looking for input, criticism, etc.

**Edit**
I forgot to include what configuration I had the modules in to produce that diagram:

```
wire ART_done;
AutoReloadTimer ART0 (
    .clk( clk ),
    .rst( rst ),
    .EN( EN ),
    .D( 4 ),
    .done( ART_done )
);

Counter uut (
    .clk(clk), 
    .rst(rst), 
    .EN(ART_done), 
    .CLR(CLR), 
    .Q(Q)
);
```

Comment: I added in the implementation I'm using - there's only one clock that they share. Still pretty new to all of this but Ciano's answer cleared up some of my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your AutoReloadTimer and Counter modules, as well as any logic that uses the done signal are on the same clock, you won't have any metastability issues.  What you would have is a fully synchronous implementation.  Naturally, you must also meet the timing requirements of the device your using

The done signal will actually change some small combinatorial path delay after the rising clock edge that causes the counter to hit 0.  Any logic that uses the done signal has the rest of the clock period before the next rising edge, to do what it needs to do (more combinatorial logic) and still meet the setup time of any register input that is conditioned by the done signal.

The metastability issues will only arise if the input to any registers are transitioning right as the clock is transitioning.  This can happen if the data that's being registered is coming from a register that uses an asynchronous clock, or if the register's setup or hold timing is violated.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense - I was having issues (in my head) understanding how the logic behaved around the clock edge. I had associated metastability with any transition occurring around a clock edge but hadn't considered the small combinational logic delay or order of events.